# How to copy to the clipboard in F#?

Tags: f#, clipboard, f#-interactive

And more specifically, in `FSI`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can programatically control the clipboard using the Clipboard class in the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace. (The required assembly is brought in by default to FSI.)

```
open System.Windows.Forms
Clipboard.SetText("Hello from FSI!")
```

Comment: I had to modify the entry to my program like so:  `[<EntryPoint; STAThread>]` according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620712/is-it-possible-to-combine-multiple-attributes-in-f and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899350/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-a-string-to-the-clipboard-in-c#comment50339862_899374.