# Is It Possible To Combine Multiple Attributes In F#?

Tags: f#, attributes

I'm trying to figure out the F# equivalent of this C# Attribute delclaration:

```
[
   ComImport(),
   InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
   Guid("000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
]
```

I can do this and it compiles fine:

```
[<ComImport>]
[<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>]
[<Guid("000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")>]
```

But I am curious now--is it possible to combine multiple attributes in F#?  When I try something like this for the first two attributes:

```
[<ComImport>,<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>]
```

I get an FS0010 error.  Also tried this:

```
[<ComImport , InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)>]
```

Same result.

Is this possible and if so what's the correct syntax?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.

```
[<
  ComImport; 
  InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown); 
  Guid("000214EE-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
>]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel--figured I was missing something obvious.

Comment: BTW Daniel is this in the F# docs?  Did I just miss seeing it in the online docs?

Comment: Yes. About halfway down [the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233179.aspx).

Comment: I'm puzzled why the semicolons can't be omitted when the attributes are on different lines (like list elements).

Comment: D'oh! I even looked at that page. That's what I get for skimming rather than reading. Thanks again for your help Daniel.