# How to copy to the clipboard in F#, specifically dotnet core fsi?

Tags: .net-core, f#, fsi

I want to set text to the clipboard in my fsi script in dotnet core.

I have used the below code from the question in the link below, which has served me well for years.
How would I do the equivalent in dotnet core / dotnet 5?

```
open System.Windows.Forms
Clipboard.SetText("Hello from FSI!")
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1791762/3172195

I can see there is some SDK Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop but for a script, I would prefer to use just a nuget package.

Comment: Just found this but I've never used it: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TextCopy/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core - copy to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205260/net-core-copy-to-clipboard)