# Get system time in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

How do I get the system time using VB.NET and copy it into the clipboard automatically?

Is there a built-in function in VB.NET for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by System Time, but if it's just the string representation of the current time then you can do the following.

```
ClipBoard.SetText(DateTime.Now.ToString())
```

This code will work in both Windows Forms and WPF.

Comment: isn't it possible to just copy the time?

Comment: `ClipBoard.SetText(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))` Alter the format specifier to customize the appearance if you like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) to get the time and Google for the code to copy to the clipboard.

Or take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899350/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-a-string-to-the-clipboard-in-c) post.

Answer (score 0):

Better use the `DateTime.UtcNow` method.
**It returns time without local format and DST offset.**

`UTC` will keep you out of trouble when storing data.
You can always format to local when export/display is needed.