# How to copy data to clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, clipboard

How can I copy a string (e.g "hello") to the System Clipboard in C#, so next time I press <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> I'll get "hello"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy the contents of a String to the clipboard in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899350/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-a-string-to-the-clipboard-in-c)

Answer (score 970, accepted):

There are two classes that lives in different assemblies and different namespaces.

- WinForms: use following namespace declaration, make sure `Main` is marked with `[STAThread]` attribute:

  ```
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  ```
- WPF: use following namespace declaration

  ```
  using System.Windows;
  ```
- console: add reference to `System.Windows.Forms`, use following namespace declaration, make sure `Main` is marked with `[STAThread]` attribute. Step-by-step guide in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34077334/477420)

  ```
  using System.Windows.Forms;
  ```

To copy an exact string (literal in this case):

```
Clipboard.SetText("Hello, clipboard");
```

To copy the contents of a textbox either use [TextBox.Copy()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.copy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_TextBoxBase_Copy) or get text first and then set clipboard value:

```
Clipboard.SetText(txtClipboard.Text);
```

[See here for an example](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial188_Clipboard-Copy-and-Paste-with-Csharp.html).
Or... [Official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydby206k.aspx) or [Here for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms597043.aspx).

---

Remarks:

- Clipboard is desktop UI concept, trying to set it in server side code like ASP.Net will only set value on the server and has no impact on what user can see in they browser. While linked answer lets one to run Clipboard access code server side with `SetApartmentState` it is unlikely what you want to achieve.
- If after following information in this question code still gets an exception see ["Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA)" error in copy string to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762037/current-thread-must-be-set-to-single-thread-apartment-sta-error-in-copy-stri)
- This question/answer covers regular .NET, for .NET Core see - [.Net Core - copy to clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205260/net-core-copy-to-clipboard)

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Is it possible to access clipboard contents using key-value pairs?

Comment: @Abdul - I'm not sure what you mean.  Clipboard contents can be text, files, images, any sort of custom data.  The concept of kv-pairs doesn't seem to be anything to do with the clipboard idea?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone what I'm attempting to make is something there an user can store multiple things in the clipboard. Those things would be accessed by a key. It's similar to HTML5 Local storage. Or is something like that not possible due to the nature of the clipboard?

Comment: If are you getting error with ASP.NET, try using into a new thread:
var thread = new Thread(param => { Clipboard.SetText(txtName.Text); });
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();

Comment: Never do this from ASP.NET.  It's a server-side technology, meaning you'll be copying to the clipboard on the server.  Worst idea ever.

Comment: skia.heliou's answer helped me: after adding attribute [STAThreadAttribute], my Clipboard.SetText method start working

Comment: For .NET Core 3.1 -- `System.Windows.Clipboard` class is available and `Clipboard.SetText` works; but I've tested only on Windows 10.

Comment: In case anyone needs to do this in uwp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/copy-and-paste

Answer (score 60):

For **console** projects in a step-by-step fashion, you'll have to first add the `System.Windows.Forms` reference. The following steps work in Visual Studio Community 2013 with .NET 4.5:

1. In **Solution Explorer**, expand your console project.
2. Right-click **References**, then click **Add Reference...**
3. In the **Assemblies** group, under **Framework**, select `System.Windows.Forms`.
4. Click **OK**.

Then, add the following `using` statement in with the others at the top of your code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Then, add either of the following [`Clipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).[`SetText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydby206k(v=vs.110).aspx) statements to your code:

```
Clipboard.SetText("hello");
// OR
Clipboard.SetText(helloString);
```

And lastly, add [`STAThreadAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your `Main` method as follows, to avoid a `System.Threading.ThreadStateException`:

```
[STAThreadAttribute]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: The class `StackOverflowException` immediately precedes `STAThreadAttribute` in the .NET Framework System Class Library =)

Answer (score 50):

My Experience with this issue using WPF C# coping to clipboard and `System.Threading.ThreadStateException` is here with my code that worked correctly with all browsers:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText("String to be copied to clipboard"));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
thread.Start(); 
thread.Join();
```

credits to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762037/error-while-trying-to-copy-string-to-clipboard)

But this works only on localhost, so don't try this on a server, as it's not going to work.

On server-side, I did it by using `zeroclipboard`. The only way, after a lot of research.

Comment: I used it in automated Selenium test (webdriver) and it works great!

Comment: @andrew.fox you tried it on your server - client model ? because if it is 2 separate machines i guess it shouldn't work.

Comment: Lol no, Selenium opens the browser window on the agent machine.

Comment: with this, you don't need [STAThreadAttribute], when you are using a console application with multiple threads

Answer (score 43):

```
Clipboard.SetText("hello");
```

You'll need to use the `System.Windows.Forms` or `System.Windows` namespaces for that.

Answer (score 9):

Clip.exe is an executable in Windows to set the clipboard. **Note** that this does not work for **other operating systems** other than Windows, which still sucks.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets clipboard to value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">String to set the clipboard to.</param>
        public static void SetClipboard(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Attempt to set clipboard with null");

            Process clipboardExecutable = new Process(); 
            clipboardExecutable.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo // Creates the process
            {
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                FileName = @"clip", 
            };
            clipboardExecutable.Start();

            clipboardExecutable.StandardInput.Write(value); // CLIP uses STDIN as input.
            // When we are done writing all the string, close it so clip doesn't wait and get stuck
            clipboardExecutable.StandardInput.Close(); 

            return;
        }
```

Comment: Worked for me after adding `UseShellExecute = false,` inside `ProcessStartInfo` as written in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=net-7.0#remarks

Comment: Also, for more than ASCII support, set `ProcessStartInfo.StandardInputEncoding` to `System.Text.Encoding` Unicode. Unless you use older .net version, then, create your own `StreamWriter` around `Process.StandardInput.BaseStream` and `Write` and `Close` *it* instead, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50001438/1997873.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to set the thread as STAThread, use `Clipboard.SetDataObject(object sthhere)`:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject("Yay! No more STA thread!");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It works, but not without STAThread. My C# WinForms program defaulted to having STAThread on Main() (in Program.cs). So it might just be a difference between old versions of VS and VS2019. Removing STAThread from Main() causes exceptions when I try to copy.

Comment: I also get an exception without STAThread and the clipboard will be emptied (instead of having that string in it). The answer seems to be incorrect, not badly supported.

Answer (score 3):

This works on .net core, no need to reference `System.Windows.Forms`

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;

DataPackage package = new DataPackage();
package.SetText("text to copy");
Clipboard.SetContent(package);
```

It works cross-platform. On windows, you can press <kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to view your clipboard history

Answer (score 1):

On ASP.net web forms use in the @page  AspCompat="true", add the system.windows.forms to you project.
At your web.config add:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
```

Then you can use:

```
Clipboard.SetText(CreateDescription());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want too or cannot use System.Windows.Forms you can use the Windows native api: user32 and the clipboard functions `GetClipboardData` and `SetClipboardDat` (pinvoke)

A .NET 6 wrapper library can be found here https://github.com/MrM40/WitWinClipboard/tree/main

Answer (score 0):

For the modern cross-platform .NET, you'll need to use the MAUI version. The short answer is `await Clipboard.Default.SetTextAsync("This text was highlighted in the UI.");` and `Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.dll` should be referenced. The long answer is covered in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/data/clipboard).