# Clipboard Data Source in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

I have been searching and searching and searching for some code that will allow me to do this but i have gotten nothing. Lets say i copied a file, or image file. It is on my clipboard. How do i get the name of the file or image file i have copied? I already know the text copied or the image, but i need the name of the file. e.g: image.png

Comment: Did you search these forums?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546016/how-to-copy-data-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp

Comment: updated question..plus i need the name of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this method?

```
Clipboard.GetFileDropList()
```

Edit:

```
StringCollection fileNameCollection = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
            string copiedFilePath = (fileNameCollection != null && fileNameCollection.Count > 0) ? fileNameCollection[0] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public System.Drawing.Image SwapClipboardImage(
System.Drawing.Image replacementImage)
{
System.Drawing.Image returnImage = null;
if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
    returnImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
    Clipboard.SetImage(replacementImage);
}
return returnImage;
}
```

from here [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getimage.aspx)

Comment: get the file name from the code I posted in chat , this is for if there is an image in clipboard