# "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA)" error in copy string to clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard

I have tried code from [How to copy data to clipboard in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546016/how-to-copy-data-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp):

```
Clipboard.SetText("Test!");
```

And I get this error:

> Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your `Main` function has `STAThreadAttribute` marked on it.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to call this method (`Clipboard.SetText()`) from a background thread? Can you give us some more context (i.e., the code surrounding that function call)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Make sure thread that runs the code is marked with [STAThread] attribute. For WinForm and console based apps it is generally `Main` method

Put `[STAThread]` above your main method:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
}
```

For WinForms it is usually in generated Main.cs file that you can edit if necessary (it will not be re-generated on changes). For console it's were you define the `Main`.

If you can't control the thread (i.e. you are writing a library or main app is locked by some reason) you can instead run code that accesses clipboard on specially configured thread (`.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)`) as shown in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17762059/477420).

Comment: I'm guessing he's using WinForms, so he doesn't have access to `Main`.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance i made one of these clipboard applications myself in winforms, so i'm pretty sure this will work for him :)

Comment: Not saying it won't work, just saying that editing `Main` on WinForms is a PITA.

Comment: @new How? It's defined in the `Main.cs` file...very simple to edit it. The main method has nothing to do with whether or not you're using WinForms. New projects have the attribute set correctly from the start, mind you.

Comment: @CodyGray Last time I saw it it was in an auto-generated file.

Comment: @new It is--`Main.cs`. Plopped right in the root directory of your project. All you have to do to edit is double-click on it. I'm not seeing the PITA.

Comment: @CodyGray I meant those that were regenerated by VS every time. Doesn't matter, as it's wrong.

Comment: If you are creating the thread yourself in Winforms just use threadvariable.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)

Answer (score 70):

If you can't control whether thread runs in STA mode or not (i.e. tests, plugin to some other app or just some code that randomly sends that call to run on no-UI thread and you can't use `Control.Invoke` to send it back to main UI thread) than you can run clipboard access on thread specifically configured to be in `STA` state which is required for clipboard access (which internally uses OLE that actually requires STA).

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText("Test!"));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); //Set the thread to STA
thread.Start(); 
thread.Join(); //Wait for the thread to end
```

Comment: This is very useful for checking clipboard contents in a Selenium test e.g. if you have a copy to clipboard button.

Comment: this solved the error for me. adding the attribute didn't.

Comment: Solved the problem. but why wasn't it allowing me to modify clipboard while the STAThread Attribute was there on main method?

Comment: Don't care any thing else, but it solved my problem.

Comment: This fixed my problem. I had a callback from a SignalR event that needed to copy something to the clipboard.

Answer (score 17):

You can only access the clipboard from an STAThread.

The quickest way to solve this is to put `[STAThread]` on top of your `Main()` method, but if for whatever reason you cannot do that you can use a separate class that creates an STAThread set/get the string value for to you.

```
public static class Clipboard
{
    public static void SetText(string p_Text)
    {
        Thread STAThread = new Thread(
            delegate ()
            {
                // Use a fully qualified name for Clipboard otherwise it
                // will end up calling itself.
                System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(p_Text);
            });
        STAThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        STAThread.Start();
        STAThread.Join();
    }
    public static string GetText()
    {
        string ReturnValue = string.Empty;
        Thread STAThread = new Thread(
            delegate ()
            {
                // Use a fully qualified name for Clipboard otherwise it
                // will end up calling itself.
                ReturnValue = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetText();
            });
        STAThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        STAThread.Start();
        STAThread.Join();

        return ReturnValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is 8 years old, but many still need the solution.

As mentioned by the others, that Clipboard must be called from the main thread or [STAThread].

Well, I use this workaround every single time. May be it can be an alternative.

```
public static void SetTheClipboard()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => {
        Clipboard.SetText("value in clipboard");
    });

    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
    t.Join();

    await Task.Run(() => {
        // use the clipboard here in another thread. Also can be used in another thread in another method.
    });
}
```

The clipboard value is created in t thread.

The key is : The thread t apartment is set to STA state.

Later you can use the clipboard value in other threads as you like.

Hope you can get the point.