# Copy from string variable and Paste Data into Textbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, clipboard, paste

I am trying to copy data from a string variable in c# like below,

```
Clipboard.SetText(StringValue));
```

and then trying to paste it using,

```
SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
```

but this is not working it throws **ThreadStateException** exception and when i try to use STA Thread like below,

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(Stringvalue));
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
SendKeys.Send("^{v}");
```

it gives me error at SendKeys.Send line about **InvalidOperationException**.

I have also tried **Sendkeys.SendWait("^{v}");** but it does not work either.

**NOTE:**

Please note that my target application is WPF and I am writing code on another application to paste the value inside my target WPF application.

Comment: Why are you setting the thread as STA?

Comment: In fact, why are you using a thread at all in this situation?

Comment: by the way, what is your actual requirement? why are you depending on clipboard and threads to paste something ?

Comment: I want to copy from a variable and paste into a textbox of another application.

Comment: @FaranSaleem: then what's the role of thread here?

Comment: @Martin I am using STA because Clipboard was having issues it was throwing an error

Comment: I was checking this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762037/current-thread-must-be-set-to-single-thread-apartment-sta-error-in-copy-stri)

Comment: SendKeys.Send("^v");  instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_SendKeys_Send_System_String_

Comment: `To specify keys combined with any combination of the SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT keys, precede the key code with one or more of the following codes.`