# It's not returning the value of the Clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetClipboard();
            Matcher();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Matcher()
        {
            string filePath = "C:\\Users\\bener\\Downloads\\wordlist.txt";
            string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            string pattern = @"\b\w+mb\b";
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(fileContents);

            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            }
        }

        static String GetClipboard()
        {
            string clipboardContent = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("Clipboard Content: " + clipboardContent);
            return clipboardContent;
        }
    }
}
```

My code is returning an empty string `""` and not the value of the clipboard.

I'm using Windows 10 and it's not a permission issue, I already ran Visual Studio as admin

I was expecting to get the contents of the clipboard, but even after verifying that I did copy a text to it, the code does not return anything.

Comment: How are you verifying that there _is_ something on the clipboard? Are you 100% certain that it is plain text (and not Unicode, HTML, or RTF text)?

Comment: I verified using the clipboard history and yes I'm 100% certain

Comment: From which application do you copy the text? What happens if you copy text from Notepad?

Comment: it still returns an empty string

Comment: Please include the exact version of runtime you use and confirm you run on Windows. (And double check you did all shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762037/current-thread-must-be-set-to-single-thread-apartment-sta-error-in-copy-stri). Ideally if you can trim code to just an [mre] it would be nicer too.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `[STAThread]` to my code that was it ):

Comment: Crucially missing an indication of  the instruction that was faulting. So where exactly did you add `[STAThread]`? Without this knowledge, readers of your Q/A don't get any wiser.