# How to copy data in a text file to the clipboard?

Tags: c#, notepad

I want to copy a data in a text file to the clipboard. This is the same sort of file you could open in Notepad, for example.

I read this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546016/how-to-copy-data-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp), it is about copying a particular given string or from textbox in a form.

But I want to copy from a file.

Comment: "notepad" is name of most basic text editor in Windows... Are you sure you are talking about "automation" of that executable? Maybe you use "notepad" as synonym of "text file"?

Comment: If u get happiness by giving minus marks for new users like me.. then do it.. thank u for discouraging us.. and insullting us

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I want to automatically copy the text.. without opening the notepad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to copy the content of a text file to `Clipboard` the use the following code:

```
Clipboard.SetText(File.ReadAllText("your file path"));
```

(Original answer, before question edit:  If you want to copy the content of a notepad to `Clipboard`, then just select the text and press `ctrl+c`. it will copy the text to the `Clipboard`.)

Comment: I want to automatically copy the text.. without opening the notepad.. thanks for ur answer..

Comment: `Clipboard.SetText(File.ReadAllText("your file path"));` will help you then. it will not open the notepad

Comment: Thank u @un-lucky.. I got the answer.. and it worked out.. it was so easy.. great

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the text in file you have, that you view using *notepad*. Notepad is not required to access that text through code. To access the text in the file you can open that file using c# file stream e.g. `StreamReader` and copy the read text to clipBoard

Reading text into string string and copying to *clipboard*.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
{
   String text = sr.ReadToEnd();
   Clipboard.SetText(text);
}
```

OR, simply

```
Clipboard.SetText(File.ReadAllText("TestFile.txt"));
```