# How to copy GridView data into clipboard in DevExpress Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How to copy GridView data into clipboard in DevExpress Winforms

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546016/how-to-copy-data-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Clipboard - Copy Data and Formatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114874) documentation article:

> DevExpress controls allow end-users to copy the control's selected data to the Clipboard using the common **CTRL+C** shortcut. These controls also provide the **CopyToClipboard** method to perform selection copying in code.

Thus, fell free to use the [BaseView.CopyToClipboard](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_CopyToClipboardtopic.aspx) and the [GridView.OptionsClipboard](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsClipboardtopic) options.

Answer (score 0):

SelectCellAnchorRange() function is used to select cell range. In this methods set both start_column and end_column same  as below

```
Grid.SelectCellAnchorRange(0, columndetails, total_rows, columndetails);
```

columndetails - which column you want to copy.