# Xamarin forms: How to copy an entry value?

Tags: xamarin.forms, clipboard, copy-paste

I want to copy a value from my app and paste it any other place of the same app or outside of the app.

I already looked for an answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546016/how-to-copy-data-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp):

So I used `Clipboard.SetText(txtClipboard.Text);` and added `using System.Windows.Forms;` and
`using System.Windows;` namespaces. But, I am getting an error:

> clipboard does not exist in the current context.

Any nuget package need for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [clipboard plugin for Xamarin](https://github.com/stavroskasidis/XamarinClipboardPlugin) (supported platforms are iOS, Mac, Android, UWP and Gtk#). It supports saving text to and getting it from the clipboard in a cross-platform way. The NuGet package is available [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugins.Clipboard/).

To set text

```
CrossClipboard.Current.SetText("my clipboard text");
```

To get text

```
string clipboardText = await CrossClipboard.Current.GetTextAsync();
```

Comment: I have some issues when copy and past text, started a new thread, can you please help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369623/xamarin-forms-pasted-test-contains-symbol-instead-of-white-space