# Xamarin Forms: Pasted test contains + symbol instead of white space

Tags: xamarin.forms, copy, clipboard, paste

Last year I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342391/xamarin-forms-how-to-copy-an-entry-value) about copy the entry value in xamarin forms.

When I test it now the white spaces in the text are filled by a + symbol. Also when pasting the emojis it is not working properly.

[image]

I am using [Xamarin.Plugins.Clipboard](https://github.com/stavroskasidis/XamarinClipboardPlugin) NuGet package for copy the text to the clipboard. When copy text to clipboard I am using the following code:

```
 CrossClipboard.Current.SetText(message);
```

When long press in the device it shows the paste option. I am using that option for pasting the copied text.

Please suggest a solution for avoiding the + symbol? Also for emoji copy paste.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `WebUtility.UrlDecode(Text)` to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem should need to **[WebUtility.UrlDecode(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urldecode?view=netframework-4.7.2)** the text :

> Converts a string that has been encoded for transmission in a URL into a decoded string.

If characters such as blanks and punctuation are passed in an HTTP stream, they might be misinterpreted at the receiving end. URL encoding converts characters that are not allowed in a URL into equivalent hexadecimal escape sequences. The UrlEncode method creates a URL-encoded string.

URL decoding replaces hexadecimal escape sequences with corresponding ASCII character equivalents. For example, when embedded in a block of URL-encoded text, the escape sequences `%3c` and `%3e` are decoded into the characters `<` and `>`.

**Sample as follow:**

```
using System.Net;    

Console.WriteLine("Encode:" + WebUtility.UrlEncode(""));
// out ==> %F0%9F%98%82

Console.WriteLine("Decode:" + WebUtility.UrlDecode("%F0%9F%98%82"));
// out ==> 

Console.WriteLine("Encode:" + WebUtility.UrlEncode("this is a text message"));
// out ==> this+is+a+text+message

Console.WriteLine("Decode:" + WebUtility.UrlDecode("this+is+a+text+message"));
// out ==> this is a text message
```

**Solution:**

Not directly `CrossClipboard.Current.SetText(message);`

Try with `CrossClipboard.Current.SetText( WebUtility.UrlDecode(message));`

Comment: Added `WebUtility.UrlEncode("message");` code when copy a message. But for paste, I am using the long press option of the device. At that time I can't add `WebUtility.UrlDecode` code.

Comment: Not adding `WebUtility.UrlEncode` , just add `WebUtility.UrlDecode(message)` before `CrossClipboard.Current.SetText(finalmessage);` I will update answer.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks for marking. writing like this:`CrossClipboard.Current.SetText( WebUtility.UrlDecode(message));`  more convenient.