# Simulate "Copy" and check text on Clipboard

Tags: c#, selenium

I am working on a test for a Web Application. I want to simulate the Copy command and verify the value of the Clipboard.

I have two ways to simulate this:

1. I simulate "Ctrl+C" by using this code:

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^{c}");
```

2. I use a button on my App which executes Copy on some text and puts it on the Clipboard

These two work and after using one of them, I can do "Ctrl+V" and it pastes the text correctly.

On my test, I am supposed to verify that the Clipboard contains the correct value.

I am using this code to check if the Clipboard is not empty and that it contains the correct string:

```cs
Clipboard.ContainsText(); // verify that Clipboard is not empty
Clipboard.GetText(); // verify that string on the Clipboard contains the good string
```

But after I simulate a Copy (with one of options above), the code just above returns respectively:

> false

> ""

Does anyone have a solution to fill the Clipboard and to see its contents?

Comment: There is no [MCVE] of the problem... So have to guess here - code does not correctly setup access to Clipboard for selenium tests (non WPF/WinForm app) which is described in standard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546016/how-to-copy-data-to-clipboard-in-c-sharp question. Please review linked question and [edit] this post to clarify how your clipboard access code is setup (preferably providing real [MCVE] at the same time)

Answer (score 1):

Ok I added this on the attribute of my test :

```cs
[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
```

I can access the value of the Clipboard now.

(Source: https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/apartment.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Clipboard.SetText("your text here")` to manually set text to the clipboard.
Afterwards, you can use `Clipboard.ContainsText()` and `Clipboard.GetText()` to check the clipboard contents as you mentioned above.

See the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard.settext?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: I've heard about this method but the issue is that this permit to manually set the Clipboard value with a specified string. I don't know this string so I can't use this. The Clipboard needs to be fill by the two ways I explained above to simulate Copy.

Comment: @Alicia Ah, so you don't currently have access to the value that is to be copied to the clipboard. I would recommend finding some way to access it, and then using `Clipboard.SetText`. What is the use case? I'm assuming you want to copy some text that is currently selected. Is that accurate?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not sure what you mean; I've never had a problem with the Clipboard functions mentioned, and I thought I _did_ mention how to read from the clipboard in my answer. If I've misunderstood the question though, I apologize, and I agree that a reproducible example would make Alicia's problem/needs more clear.

Comment: @inejwstine write console app to read/write clipboard (you can easily add `System.Windows.Forms` refence to access `Console` class) to have some problems… Note that it is somewhat said in the question - "test" and "selenium" pretty much guarantees that it is console based app...