# How can I copy a string to the clipboard within my console application WITHOUT adding a reference to System.Windows.Forms?

Tags: .net, console-application, clipboard

I have a .NET 4.0 console application that generates SQL and stores it in a string variable. I want this string to be copied directly to the clipboard.

So far, all my research indicates that the ONLY way this can possibly be done is by adding a reference to System.Windows.Forms. I do not want to add a reference to an assembly that is irrelevant to a console application.

Within the universe in which we currently exist, is there a known method of copying a string of text to the clipboard within a console application that does not involve adding a reference to System.Windows.Forms nor any other assembly whose purpose is irrelevant to a bare-bones console application?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[Platform invoking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services) the clipboard APIs is a possible solution. Example:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool OpenClipboard(IntPtr hWndNewOwner);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool CloseClipboard();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool SetClipboardData(uint uFormat, IntPtr data);

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenClipboard(IntPtr.Zero);
        var yourString = "Hello World!";
        var ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(yourString);
        SetClipboardData(13, ptr);
        CloseClipboard();
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
```

This is just an example. Adding a little error handling around the code, like checking the return values of the P/Invoke functions, would be a good addition.

[`SetClipboardData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051(v=vs.85).aspx) is the interesting bit. You also want to make sure you open and close the clipboard, too.

The `13` passed in as the first argument is the data format. 13 [means a Unicode string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729168(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Sweet!  It works.  I will add that I needed to import the System.Runtime.InteropServices namespace.  Other than that, it works!

Comment: Thanks! vcsjones, actually, this method crushes sometimes (I really don't know the reason). The answer bellow with the class Clippy fixes the crushes in my app. Thanks anyway

Comment: Besides the `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26054040/33499), I read on MSDN "_If SetClipboardData succeeds, the system owns the object identified by the hMem parameter. The application may not write to or free the data_".

Answer (score 9):

The `Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni` function actually allocates memory in a fashion unsuitable for `SetClipboardData (using LocalAlloc with LMEM_FIXED)`, which can cause crashes (you wouldn't expect it given the method name, but stepping into the code e.g. using [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) reveals this).

`SetClipboardData` requires `GlobalAlloc` with `GMEM_MOVABLE` according to the documentation: [SetClipboardData on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649051(v=vs.85).aspx).

Here's an MIT licensed System.Windows.Forms alternative, tested and complete with error handling: [Clippy](https://github.com/kolibridev/clippy)

(The clipboard pushing code itself is to be found here: [Clippy.cs](https://github.com/kolibridev/clippy/blob/master/Clippy/Clippy.cs).)