# How to close the clipboard ressource in C#?

Tags: c#, clipboard, concurrent-programming, clipboard-interaction

Below is the code how I put a text string into the Windows Clipboard. I am looking for a command to close the clipboard resource immediately after so that it is not locked anymore by the app. Do you know how to close the clipboard ressource explicitely in C#?

This is the code

```
String s = "Hello World";
Thread staThread3 = new Thread
(
    delegate()
    {
        try { new SetClipboardHelper(DataFormats.Text, s).Go();}
        catch (Exception ex)  { /* Exception Handling */ }
    }
);
staThread3.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
staThread3.Start();
staThread3.Join();
// Here I would like to close the clipboard
// ????
```

This is the code of class SetClipboardHelper

```
class SetClipboardHelper : StaHelper
{
    readonly string _format;
    readonly object _data;

    public SetClipboardHelper(string format, object data)
    {
        _format = format;
        _data = data;
    }

    protected override void Work()
    {
        var obj = new System.Windows.Forms.DataObject(
            _format,
            _data
        );

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(obj, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: _so that it is not locked anymore by the app_ - What does this mean?

Comment: You might want to add that you got the classes you use from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899350/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-a-string-to-the-clipboard-in-c) because they are not part of the .NET Framework.

Comment: I'm assuming that an application is locking the usage of the clipboard ressource for a certain amount of time before another application can use it.

Comment: @nvoigt that is correct. I got already a lot of help from the stackoverflow community. It is the best place for coding people :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "lock" (prevent other apps to modify) the clipboard by calling [OpenClipboard()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, then you can (and you should, because it prevents other applications from using it) close it with [CloseClipboard()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Copying_Information_to_the_Clipboard)'s a sequence you should stick to when copying to the clipboard.

Comment: You gave links to C API, not C#.