# C# Copy to Clipboard

Tags: c#, clipboard

I'd like to make a console application in C#, where the user will type something, let's say "Dave" and then it'll output "Name: Dave" and copy the "Name: Dave" to the users clipboard. So is there a way to have the "Name: " + Console.ReadLine(); copied to the users clipboard automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy the contents of a String to the clipboard in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/899350/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-a-string-to-the-clipboard-in-c)

Answer (score 52):

You'll need to reference a namespace:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Then you can use:

```
Clipboard.SetText("Whatever you like");
```

**EDIT**

Here's a copy and paste solution that works for me

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Say something and it will be copied to the clipboard");

            var something = Console.ReadLine();

            Clipboard.SetText(something);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows'. Are you missing 'System.Windows.Forms' assembly reference?

Comment: You will need to add a reference to System.Windows.Forms - right click on project, click Add Reference.

Comment: Ok thank you, but it isn't copying it to my Clipboard:
                            
Console.WriteLine ("Say something and it'll be copied to your clipboard");
string something = Console.ReadLine ();
   System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(something);

Comment: It might work on windows, but it certainly doesn't work on mac:(

Comment: Are you on a wind up? Your question is about C#. NO mention of mac anywhere

Comment: I'm coding in MonoDevelop on a Mac. My program is apparently crashing when it tries to add to clipboard, did I mess something up? Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/mJnqu9EX

Comment: this was CRUCIAL information omitted from the original question.

Comment: The [STAThread] attribute MUST be present on the Main method, else this doesn't work.

Comment: For all of the mentioned problems, look at my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563643/5827730

Answer (score 21):

Use

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(message)
```

where message is the string to be copied.

Although the System.Windows.Forms namespace was designed for Windows Forms, many methods from its API have valuable uses even in console / other non-Winforms applications.

Comment: beaten by exactly 6 seconds! haha

Comment: I want to Copy a string to the clipboard in C# Console Application.
System.Windows.Forms: not working in Console App.

Comment: Try the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563643/2902555) to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`.

Answer (score 6):

1: You need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` as follows:

Right-click your project in `Solution Explorer` and select `Add reference`... and then find `System.Windows.Forms` and add it. ([look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21951618/5827730))

2: Then you can add `System.Windows.Forms` to your code using the line below and make sure you place it correctly where it should be with other `using`(s):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

3: Add `[STAThread]` on the top of your `Main` function, so it should be like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      ....
}
```

4: Use `Clipboard` as you like, for example:

```
Clipboard.SetText("Sample Text");
```