# how to add System.Windows.Forms in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net

i used visual studio 2010 and i need to add System.Windows.Forms in my project but when i am trying to add this then it shows error i.e.

[image]

please give me solution for this

Comment: What kind of project do you have? How are you adding the reference?

Comment: Provide more details on what you are trying to do

Comment: How did you do, and what is System_Window_Forms ??

Comment: i am working in Visual Studio 2010 Asp.net Web Application and i am trying to add reference from Website --> Add Reference --> .NET Component. But here System.Window.Forms is not available in list

Answer (score 11):

**Problem:** You are trying to add the `System_Windows_Forms` from `COM` tab of `Reference Manager` window.

Problem here:

[image]
**Solution :** You need to Add `System.Windows.Forms` from `Assemblies -> Framework`  Tab of  `Reference Manager` window.

Select as below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A console application does not automatically add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll.

Right-click your project in Solution Explorer and select Add reference... and then find System.Windows.Forms and add it.

and

> Did you try to add it from the COM-tab? Find the System.Windows.Forms.dll in the .NET-tab instead!

[image]

Comment: but i am using visual studio 2010

Comment: so what? that's not a problem for your question.

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2010. Add Reference -> ".NET" tab -> System.Windows.Forms

If you cant see it there, then check to what .NET framework version your project is set (Add reference should show you to what version it filters libraries or check project properties.) and make sure you have that version installed.

How to find installed versions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit:
Also, if you are using Vista or later, you should migrate your project to .NET 4 if it already isn't.

.NET 4 installer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851

.NET 3.5 installer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21

If you are using Windows 8 or 8.1 here is how you can enable older framework versions: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do this. You mention you have a web application and you are adding windows form DLL to it. This is not correct way of doing whatever it is that you are doing. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?